# How to increments or decrements of a value in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to fix the brightness issue on my laptop by manually editing parameters via CLI.

How would I add increments or decrements of 50 to the current value?

```
echo 150 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness 
echo 200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
```

Rather than echoing a fix value, I want to say add +50 or remove -50 from the value present in the brightness file (currently holding between 0 / 255)

Thanks

P

Comment: Read the current value first, increase it and then echo the new value to the file?

Comment: `echo $(( $(< /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness) + 50 )) | ...`

Comment: fwiw, `xbacklight` lets you increment/decrement by percentages as well as setting to absolute values, and you don't need to be root

Comment: this should be on [unix.se]

Answer (score 0):

I can use `xrandr`.

List your screens:

```
xrandr -q
```

Modify the brightness in screen **`HDMI-0`**:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 0.7
```

Example:

[image: Using xrandr]